# When to use "pas" vs. "non" in expressing "not [adjective/adverb]"?

Tags: grammaire, usage, négation, adverbes

Sometimes I see it written one way, such as *non seulement* for *not only*, and sometimes the other way, with *pas*. When to use which? Is there a difference? Are they interchangeable?

I don't mean with phrases such as "Je ne sais pas," "Je ne sais non" is obviously wrong. I just mean when you're saying short responses/phrases by themselves like "not really," "not only," "not always," "not often," etc.

Comment: Question non triviale et pas facile !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Metalinguistic negation

There is a particular use of *non*, which has been mentioned in other answers. Even though I'm not an expert, I think all similar cases I will mention here are cases of [metalinguistic negation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_%28linguistique%29#N.C3.A9gation_non_v.C3.A9riconditionelle), hence the name of this section. These *non* negate (or expand on, or nuance) a previous claim, or hypothetic (or sometimes obvious) assumptions one could make.

1. The first form is “*Non … mais …*”.

   > Votre participation est non acceptée mais encouragée.

   This could imply that the term *acceptée* was used previously. Someone thought it would convey bad connotations, and suggested that “*encouragée*” is the appropriate word using this phrasing.
2. This same *non* can be used with a few adverbs (chiefly *seulement*, but also *véritablement*, *vraisemblablement*, and maybe others), to introduce nuances. Examples:

   > Cela est non seulement incongru, c'est aussi complètement stupide.
   >   Il a agit non véritablement par nécessité, mais plutôt par compassion.
3. It can also introduce a sentence:

   > Non seulement il ne fait pas d'efforts, mais en plus il nous embête.
4. Or can appear in phrasings such as:

   > La Terre, qui est plutôt sphérique et non planaire comme l'ont pensé certains.
5. It can also be found as an incise clause (the following is a quote including one of the very few *non toujours* you will ever find):

   > Un des propres de leur race est, dans le feu de la jonction, de se jurer mutuellement, non toujours par convenance, qu'ils sont unis ad aeternum.

All these phrasings can also be formulated with a standard *ne … pas* négation, and the power of the negation is somehow lessened. For cases number 3 (and 5) it might be a bit difficult to find the appropriate phrasing, because just substituting *non* with *pas* is not an option:

> 1. Votre participation n'est pas acceptée mais encouragée.
> 2. Cela n'est pas seulement incongru, c'est aussi complètement stupide.
> 3. **Ce** n'**est** pas seulement **qu**'il ne fait pas d'efforts, mais **c**'**est** **qu**'en plus il nous embête.
> 4. La terre, qui est plutôt sphérique et n'est pas planaire comme l'ont pensé certains.
> 5. … de se jurer mutuellement, **ce** n'**est** pas toujours par convenance, qu'ils …

#### Standard negation

*Non* is also an adverb which is sometimes used produce plain standard negation.
Here are few remarks, which I hope will help clarify when its use is possible (if not required).

1. There is a subtle difference between these two sentences:

   > Sa décision n'est pas contestable.
   >   Sa décision est incontestable.

   The first exposes a subjective property (you cannot argue his decision, maybe nobody can); and the second exposes an intrinsic property (it's impossible).

   To give another example:

   > Cette personne n'est pas fréquentable.
   >   Cette personne est infréquentable.

   The first meaning (subjective attribution) is “you shall/can not get acquainted with this person”; and the second (intrinsic attribution) would be “nobody can”.

   To obtain the same effect with an adjective that does not have a pre-existing opposite, *non* is used:

   > Sa décision n'est pas négociable.
   >   Sa décision est non négociable.

   In particular, the latter will be perceived as more absolute/authoritative.
2. Using *non* before an adjective which admits a straightforward opposite would sound odd, use *difficile* instead *non facile*, *basse* instead of *non haute*, etc.

   Though, there are lots specific cases which might require some more care, for example, *réaliste* can be negated as *non réaliste* even though *irréaliste* exists, because that word could also be interpreted as “pertinent to irreality” (which is not quite the same thing).
3. The subjective/intrinsic distinction also applies when adjectives are used as epithets:

   > Une personne (qui n'est) *pas* fréquentable. (subjective)
   >   Une personne infréquentable. (intrinsic)
   >
   > Une décision (qui n'est) *pas* négociable.
   >   Une décision *non* négociable.

   Note: I think there is something slightly wrong with the omission of “*qui n'est*” in a formal usage, but you will of course find it omitted quite often.
4. Adverbs.

   *Non* is also used to negate adverbs. In particular it assumes that negated adverbs don't have pre-existing opposites. For example *faussement* is to be preferred to *non vraiment*.

   Some subtle distinction between a subjective or intrinsic intention is sometimes still present.

   > Un rapport non clairement établi entre fréquence et durée
   >   Un rapport qui n'est pas clairement établi entre fréquence et durée

   The topic of first phrasing is a correlation with an unclear footing while in the second sentence the topic is a correlation, with the additional information that it has an unclear footing. Is the difference noticeable?

   Also, the reason why “*non toujours*” and “*non souvent*” are extremely rare is that occurrences are generally not an intrinsic property of what is being described. Moreover “*non souvent*” would more likely be replaced by “rarement“.

Comment: I think you'd say "jamais" instead of "non toujours" and "rarement" instead of "non souvent". Actually, I cannot remember ever reading/hearing "non toujours" or "non souvent". That sounds really weird.

Comment: @Alexis: “Jamais” is not the negation of “toujours”… There's a big difference between “quelque chose qui n'arrive jamais” and “quelque chose qui n'arrive pas toujours”. And “rarement” would be similar to “pas souvent” (which also occurs very often).

Comment: It took me a year, but..accepted.

Answer (score 8):

1. Dans tous ces cas on utilise *pas*, *non* n'est pas possible :

   - pas vraiment  (*not really*)
   - pas toujours  (*not always*)
   - pas souvent  (*not often*)
2. *ne … pas … seulement* et *non … seulement* sont interchangeables :
   « Je veux *non seulement* réussir mais arriver le premier » ou « Je *ne* veux *pas seulement* réussir mais arriver le premier » veulent dire la même chose.

Comment: Ce n'est pas si simple, il n'y a pas seulement ces cas-là. « Non seulement » est toujours suivi d'un exemple de ce qui est aussi présent (« il y a non seulement ces cas-là, mais aussi le cas où la clause est seule »). Quand on peut remplacer « ne … pas seulement » par « ne … que », on ne peut pas utiliser « non seulement ».

Answer (score 4):

I think you can easily spare yourself the trouble of remembering when to use *"non"* instead of *"pas"* for *"not"*, since 95% of the time *"pas"* is **not** replaceable with *"non"*. And conversely, cases when you **must** use *"non"* for *not* and couldn't use *"pas"* are very, very rare.

Actually, the only ones I can think of are *"Non seulement"* and *"Non loin de"* starting a sentence.

> Non seulement il était tard, mais il faisait froid. *(correct)*
>
> Pas seulement il était tard, mais il faisait froid. *(incorrect)*

.

> Non loin de là vivait un homme... *(correct)*
>
> Pas loin de là vivait un homme... *(understandable but sounds like a mix of informal and formal speech, you don't really say that)*

Of course you've got *"non"*-prefixed adjectives or nouns like *"non-violent"*, *"non-prolifération"* but these are the same in English so they are basically *no-brainers* - which by the way you'll have trouble translating either with "non" or "pas" ;)

Comment: In French only nouns are prefixed with *non-* with a hyphen, for adjectives and adverbs *non* is simply an adverb, so it comes without a hyphen.

Comment: That's not what my Larousse says : *non-violent*, *non-viable*...

Comment: Then Larousses contradict one another, there is another one here which says [*non viable* (adjective)](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionnaires/francais/non_viable/54951). About [*non-violent*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionnaires/francais/non_violent_non_violente/54953), it is in most cases used as a noun, but when it's an adjective there is no hypen.

Answer (score 2):

It's mainly a matter of which French expression is used: *Non seulement* is often used as the exact translation of *not only* when you have this kind of sentence: *Non seulement ... mais en plus ... !*. So it's when you're building a complete argument sentence by your own.

*Pas seulement* is used another way. It's what you would say when someone said something right and you have some other thing to add to its argument.

Otherwise, there is not any concrete rule about *non* and *pas*: you have to figure out which one is used depending on the sentence and the context.

Comment: Great...it's a case-by-case thing? @$)%*@

Comment: -1 for saying "no rule" when answering a learner. [Be prescriptivist (sometimes)](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/7955/68076).