# Can "ne... pas que" mean "Not only"?

Tags: grammaire, négation

Can "ne... pas que" mean "not only"?

Can you say "I don't just eat that" and translate it as

> Je ne mange pas que ça

Can you say "It's not just for that" and translate it as

> Ce ne sert pas qu'à ça

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.

"Not only" means literally "pas seulement" in french.

> Je ne mange pas seulement des pommes

Is correct. But if you don't use the "mais" (meaning "but") after it, it is correct, but we are usually expecting something behind it.

> Je ne mange pas seulement des pommes mais aussi des bananes
>
> Je mange non seulement des pommes mais aussi des bananes

Is correct too, it insist on the fact you don't eat only apple.

> Je ne mange pas que ça

Doesn't need something behind it, but you can say :

> Je ne mange pas que ça, mais aussi ceci

Correct too.

> ça ne sert qu'à ça

It is not **ce** but **ça**. The rest is correct.

If you want to understand the meaning of **non**, this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3114/when-to-use-pas-vs-non-in-expressing-not-adjective-adverb/3116#3116) might help you ! :)