# Ce n'est pas possible contre c'est impossible : Différences ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs, négation

> Ce n'est pas possible contre c'est impossible.
>
> Ce n'est pas logique contre c'est illogique.
>
> Ce n'est pas lisible contre c'est illisible.

etc.

Les deux tournures sont-elles équivalentes (à savoir celle avec la négation et celle avec le contraire de l'adjectif) ? Quand faut-il employer l'une et quand l'autre ?
Dans l'oral je pense que l'on préfère la construction avec la négation, non ?

Comment: Autre question sur le même sujet : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3114/when-to-use-pas-vs-non-in-expressing-not-adjective-adverb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne crois pas possible de généraliser une réponse sur la différence entre ce que l'on appelle la négation libre (pas xyzt) et la négation préfixale (in/im/irr/a...xyzt)

Ducrot dit la première *descriptive* et la seconde *polémique*. Mais... si c'est souvent évident... cela ne marche pas toujours.

Leeman, pour les adjectifs associés à un procès, (cas fréquent des adjectifs en -ble comme ici ton illisible) associe la négation libre à la négation du procès (ici de lecture) et la négation préfixale à la négation d'une qualité / propriété (de l'objet lu)

Sans compter les cas dans lesquels l'adjectif préfixé et l'adjectif ne sont pas antonymes... (pitoyable, croyable, appréciable...)

Le plus curieux dans cette histoire étant le fait amplement rapporté dans des sondages auprès d'auditeurs que si l'adjectif représente une qualité positive, la négation libre est systématiquement perçue comme l'expression d'un défaut alors que l'adjectif préfixé, et bien qu'antonyme, ne le sera pas nécessairement. (Hamma rapporte l'exemple de *interprétable*)

Comme quoi... entre ce qu'en disent les linguistes, ce qu'en perçoivent les lecteurs... il est très certainement des différences / nuances entre les deux formes de négation mais... il vaut mieux y aller au cas par cas.

En particulier ici avec ton *logique* pour cause d'ambigüité : *illogique* n'est pas ambigu alors que *pas logique* l'est. (*illogique* ou *alogique*) ? Il en irait de même avec *moral* et bien d'autres...

EDIT : J'avais ignoré le problème de la gradation. On entendra souvent que les choses (ne) sont *(pas) **très / peu** possibles, lisibles, logiques* quand ***très /peu*** impossible, illisible, illogique sont beaucoup plus rares voire inusités.

Comment: Il y a aussi, concernant la gradation, **à peu près**. «À peu près impossible» est commun, mais «à peu près possible» beaucoup moins. «À peu près correct» commun, mais pas «à peu près incorrect». «À peu près lisible» à peu près aussi naturel qu’«à peu près illisible». Cher aCOSwt, rappelez aussi à Pandore Montée-de-lait de ne pas ouvrir la boîte...

Comment: @Montéedelait : Si vous êtes Pandore... qui serais-je pour vous en empêcher ? Et en fin de compte... si, comme de bons auteurs l'assurent, c'est bien l'espoir que vous gardez dans cette boîte alors... je vous serai au contraire reconnaissant de... ne pas le garder juste pour vous... ;-)

Comment: pour la gradation, on pourrait également utiliser "presqu'impossible"

Answer (score 2):

*(Ne) pas lisible* et *illisible* sont interchangeables, mais *illisible* est d'un registre un peu plus soutenu.

> Ce texte n'est pas lisible.
>
> Ce texte est illisible.

*Pas possible* et *impossible* sont parfois difficilement interchangeables:

> C'est pas possible, il est encore en retard ! (<s>C'est impossible, il est encore en retard !</s>)
>
> Impossible n'est pas français. (<s>Pas possible n'est pas français.</s>)

Answer (score 0):

D'après la définition du préfixe (TLFi) on obtient la même chose qu'avec la négation par le verbe.

> Préf. négatif, issu du préf. négatif lat. in-, entrant dans la formation de très nombreux adj. (notamment en -able et en -é/-ée), plus rarement de subst.; il sert à indiquer la négation, la privation, l'absence ou le contraire de qqc.; le rad., gén. un adj., parfois un verbe, existe aussi dans d'assez nombreux termes empr. directement au latin.

Il peut cependant y avoir une légère différence dans l'emploi de la forme utilisant le préfixe avec un adjectif; cela dépendra du contexte apparemment; au lieu de « impossible » le préfixe peut signifier « difficile à accomplir, à trouver, à comprendre, etc. ».

- incompossible, in-compossible , philos. « Qui ne peut exister en même temps qu'une autre chose ».
- indécouvrable. « Qu'il est impossible ou difficile de découvrir ».
- indéfaisable. « Qu'il est impossible ou difficile de défaire ».
- indétachable. « Qu'il est impossible ou difficile de détacher ».
- inémotif, -ive. « Qui n'est pas émotif ».
- insoulevable. « Qu'il est impossible ou difficile de soulever ».

Dans la langue parlée les deux possibilités sont utilisables de façon équivalente au moins pour les expressions courantes comme « C'est impossible. »; pour les moins courantes comme « Ils sont inessentiels.», les gens diront plus souvent « Ils ne sont pas essentiels. »; c'est ce qu'il me semble tout au moins.